# Pandas: Sorting by week number and year string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I had a list of dates that turned into week number and years using;

```
dfweek['weeknum'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%U_%Y')
```

This would output: 34_2019

34 being the 34th week of 2019

How would I go about sorting data by this string in chronological order since the order comes out:

```
00_2018
00_2019
01_2018
01_2019
```

I tried converting back to datetime by:

```
dfweek['weeknum1'] = pd.to_datetime(dfweek['weeknum'], format = '%W_%Y')
```

This kept returning the error: ValueError: Cannot use '%W' or '%U' without day and year

Tried adding a day in the form of %w just to see what happens

```
dfweek['weeknum'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%U_%Y_%w')
dfweek['weeknum1'] = pd.to_datetime(dfweek['weeknum'], format = '%W_%Y_%w')
```

but it just spits back the original date without the week number

My desired output would be

```
00_2018
01_2018
02_2018
...
51_2019
52_2019
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following for the sorting:

```
dfweek = dfweek.assign(weeknum1= df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y_%U')).sort_values('weeknum1')
```

Here, we made a temporary column `weeknum1` using format e.g. '2018_00' and then sort using this format.  As a result, it is sorting in year + week number as required.